# How to Call Java Bean Method Before Ajax Call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a web page by using Java, Spring and PrimeFaces and I want to call a java bean method before opening a popup via AJAX by using `commandButton`.

```
<f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{bean.method}"/>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.method}"/>
```

I tried above codes , `f:event` does not help to me because I am not reloading the page, I am using AJAX.

`@PostConstruct` does not help me due to same reason as above.

Properties of `commandButton` as; `onsuccess, onstart, onerror, oncomplete, onclick` etc. does not help me

I need a solution on Java side, I need to manipulate ajax rendering, I mean i want to change some `commanButton` properties before ajax rendering. There should be an annotation or something like that in Java bean which allows me to manipulate component properties before ajax rendering. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Your browser will not usually run any Java. Java runs before page is sent to client, and all "clever" methods are hidden HTTP calls themselves. As a result, what you actually want is to intercept your AJAX call handling, not the call itself. Or use Javascript.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov actually `onstart` provides my request, it calls method before page is rendered by AJAX, but i have to get same property on Java side because of some reasons. I need to provide `onstart` property on Java side.

Comment: In future [jsf] questions please don't use [java] tag as long as problem is not demonstrable using a plain vanilla Java application with main() method. Otherwise you risk getting confusing/misleading comments from [java] users who know nothing about [jsf].

Comment: Thanks @BalusC , I have been following you for a long time, you are good at especially jsf and primefaces. Could you help to me to overcome of this challenge? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<commandButton  actionListener="#{mybean.beanFunction()}" update="mywidget" oncomplete="mypopup.open()"/>`. With commandButton you can call a bean, update some html and finally call a javascript function. If you like to call a bean at any time, you can use `<p:remoteCommand name="myfunction" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" actionListener="#{mybean.beanFunction()}" update="mywidget" oncomplete="mypopup.open()"/>` and then call from javascript `myfunction()`.

Comment: As i mentioned above i can not use oncomplete due to some reasons. @Holger

Comment: @GökhanPolat first you wrote 'do not help me'. Now you wrote 'can not use'. Why can't you use oncomplete? Please write, on which event (server/client side) what has to be called, what has to be updated and what should finally pop up?